# Remove element from Javascript associative array using array value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove an element from a Javascript associtive array using the value to find it, but I am having trouble. I have tried splice and JQuery's grep method and neither have worked for me. This is what I currently have.

```
var array_path = new Array();

function bulk_upload(){

var temp_array = new Object();

for (var i = 1; i<8; i++){

        temp_array[i] = $('#path' + i).val();

        if(temp_array[i]!='' && temp_array[i]!=null){

            array_path['path' + i] = $('#path' + i).val();

        }

}
process_txt();
}

function process_txt(){

//alert(array_path.indexOf(full_path)); //returns nothing

var removed_element = array_path.splice(getKey(array_path), 1);

//array_path = $.grep(array_path, function(val) { return val != full_path; });

alert(removed_element);//return nothing, just blank alert box

}

function getKey(data) {
  for (var prop in data)
    return prop;
}
```

Comment: "array_path = new Array();" is the worst way to say "array_path  = []"

Comment: Sorry getKey is my own function. I have added it now.

Comment: @Valya - would you like to elaborate and would this solve my problem?

Comment: What is `process_txt()` supposed to be searching for in `array_path`? Could you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish with that function?

Comment: @Abs, like that, your getKey function always returns the first key. Is that what the function is supposed to do?

Comment: Your code is seriously broken: You can't use array methods with non-numeric 'keys' as these are regular object properties; also, why did you introduce `temp_array` (which is no array at all) if you only ever access a single value? Why do you push up to 8 elements to an array (at least I think that's what you wanted to do), but only process one of them?

Comment: @Miguel - this was just an outline of my code to show what I am trying to do. Yes, getKey will return the first key, but the problem is I just want to delete an element, this is something that I can not even do!

Comment: @Christoph - I process one of them at a time - like I have said to Miguel - this is only partial code that I have simplified. The actual question here is how do I delete an element of an array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way to do this is to use the `delete` operator.

```
delete array_path[getKey(array_path)]
```

#### Some Background Information

In JavaScript, almost everything descends from `Object.prototype`.  JavaScript, being an open and dynamic language allows you to create/modify properties of objects by simple assignment.  This is very similar to what an *associative array* -- a structure that contains keyed values.

Under the hood an array is just an object that descends from `Array.prototype` with numeric keys and a special property called `length`.  The `length` property just returns one greater than the highest numeric property.  In essence, an `Array` is an object with different semantics.

If you're wanting an *associative array* then `Array` is not the object you want to descend from.  You would want to descend directly from `Object`.  There are two ways to do that, you could either use the `new` operator or an empty object literal.  The syntax for both is below:

```
var o = new Object();
var o = {};
```

The second is preferred since it's a little bit more concise.

I wrote a [blog post](http://bryan-kyle.blogspot.com/2009/04/array-is-not-map-in-javascript-arrays.html) about this a while back, have a look if you want a little bit more info.

Answer (score 8):

There is no such thing in JavaScript as an "associative array" per se. The data structure which corresponds to this concept is simply a JavaScript Object.

Of course, a JavaScript Array (like essentially everything in JavaScript) is an Object, but one with additional capabilities. So you can use an Array as a key-value map, but it's really not the correct structure for that.

To remove a key from an Object, you just do something like this:

```
var myObj = {};
var myKey = "blah";

myObj[myKey] = 1234; // Adds or updates value for "blah" to 1234.

delete myObj[myKey]; // Removes key-value pair for "blah".
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `delete hash.someKey;` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can give your object a remove method, or use apply or call to use another object's remove method, if defined.

```
function myObj(members){
 for(var p in members) this[p]= members[p];
}

myObj.prototype.remove= function(val){
 for(var p in this){
  if(this[p]=== val) delete this[p];
 }
 return this;
}

myObj.prototype.toString= function(){
 var  A= [];;
 for(var p in this){
  if(this.hasOwnProperty(p)){
   A.push(p+':'+this[p])
  }
 }
 return '{'+A.join(', ')+'}';
}

var O= new myObj({a: 1, b: 10, c: 100});
alert(O)
O.remove(10);
alert(O)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not psychic, so I can only guess that you wanted to accomplish something like this:

```
var paths = [];

function getPaths() {
    for(var i = 1; i < 8; ++i) {
        var value = $('#path' + i).val();
        if(value) paths.push(value);
    }
}

function process() {
    var firstPath = paths.shift();
    // do stuff
}

getPaths();
if(paths.length) process();
```